# Setting heartbeat interval in Android Async library by Koushik Dutta

Tags: android, androidasync-koush

I am using com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.3 as Android SocketIO client library. Is there a way to change the default heartbeat interval in the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heartbeat is defined [here](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/blob/c6095db1312045f798dad54c46190de8c5d419ef/AndroidAsync/src/com/koushikdutta/async/http/socketio/SocketIOConnection.java)

```
connecting = httpClient.executeString(request, null)
.then(new TransformFuture<SocketIOTransport, String>() {
    @Override
    protected void transform(String result) throws Exception {
        String[] parts = result.split(":");
        final String sessionId = parts[0];
        if (!"".equals(parts[1]))
            heartbeat = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) / 2 * 1000;
        else
            heartbeat = 0;
```

It does have a fallback value of 0, but it gets its *real* value from

```
Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) / 2 * 1000;
```

[According to koush himself](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/issues/63):

> The heartbeat used by AndroidAsync is derived from the value sent from the server:
>
> ```
> heartbeat = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) / 2 * 1000;
> ```

You cannot change the heartbeat value manually.

Comment: how should I change the heartbeat value set by server?

Comment: @windchime that depends on the server platform and language, cannot help you with that